# Pinescript - variable set to 0 returns a non zero value when referenced with an index

Tags: pine-script

I'm having an hard time debugging a Pinescript indicator. Here is the code

```
//@version=4
study("Trend Regularity Adaptive Moving Average","TRAMA",overlay=true)
length=input(99),src = input(close)
//----
ama = 0.
//debugging part
txt = tostring(ama[1])
x = bar_index
y = src
//end of debugging part
label.new(x, y, txt) // print value of close
hh = max(sign(change(highest(length))),0)
ll = max(sign(change(lowest(length))*-1),0)
tc = pow(sma(hh or ll ? 1 : 0,length),2)
ama := nz(ama[1]+tc*(src-ama[1]),src)
plot(ama,"Plot",#ff1100,2)
```

What i don't understand is the value of `ama[1]`. Here `ama` is declared to be `0`, but `ama[1]` returns a non zero value. From what i understood, in Pinescript `[1]` should return the value of the previous bar, but since in this case `ama` is set to be 0, how is it possible that it returns a non zero value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are re-assigning a value to `ama` with `ama := nz(ama[1]+tc*(src-ama[1]),src)`.

The way this works is, if `ama[1]+tc*(src-ama[1])` is `na`, `ama` will be `src`. If it is not `na`, it will be `ama[1]+tc*(src-ama[1])`.

> *nz(source, replacement) → simple float*
>
> **RETURNS** 
> The value of `source`
> if it is not `na`. If the value of `source` is `na`, returns zero, or
> the `replacement` argument when one is used.
>
> **ARGUMENTS**
> **source (series int/float/bool/color)** Series of values to process.
> **replacement (series int/float/bool/color)** Value that will replace all ‘na’ values in the `source` series.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that initially ama[1] is equal to 0 before being reassigned?

Comment: `ama[1]` will always be equal to `ama`'s last value on the previous bar.